# Sunday only on Jquery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

AIM: TO only allow users to select sunday on the datpicker calendar.

Currently I have it almost done, except for some reason every other day except Sunday works. When I use 7 for Sunday in the code below the entire calendar is unclickable, any other day works perfect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({ 
        autoSize: true,         // automatically resize the input field 
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  // Date Format used
        firstDay: 1, // Start with Monday
        beforeShowDay: function(date)

        { return [date.getDay() == 7,''];}}); // Allow only one day a week
});
```

Question: How can I only allow Sunday selection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Date.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns a value in the range `0-6`, not `1-7`.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [date.getDay() === 0,''];
}
```